# Does it possible to create virtual file system to install programms?

Tags: windows, file, system, virtual

I use shared Windows system where I have limited rights to Program Files, registry etc.
But I can install program if it doesn't request all above - doesn't request installation. E.g. Firefox Portable.
May be exists some workaround that can be used for all kind of program? Like virtual file system - if this have sense. But only not something like VMware - I have limited memory resources.